# sql update statement conflict with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, foreign-keys, sql-update

I am trying to update a sql table with this stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdatePostingStatusAngel]
     @PostingStatusID tinyint,
     @PostingID int
AS
UPDATE dbo.Posting
SET
    PostingStatusID = @PostingStatusID
WHERE PostingID = @PostingID
```

When I am executing that query I am getting this error: `The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Posting_PaymentStatus". The conflict occurred in database "JobsDB2008", table "dbo.PaymentStatus", column 'PaymentStatusID'.`

This is really weird because I am not updating 'PaymentStatusID' column I don't know why it gives me conflict on that column. That column is also set to NULL and it has value already.
I am trying to update only PostingStatusID field.
Any idea what can be the reason?
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: Could you edit your post an include the two tables definitions?

Comment: Assuming your foreign key is actually defined correctly and references `PaymentStatusId` rather than `PostingStatusId` then at some point the foreign key was probably disabled the re-enabled with out the `WITH CHECK` option. This would leave invalid data in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value stored in the `PaymentStatusId` column must not exist in the `PaymentStatus` table.

Ensure that `PostingStatusId`, `PaymentStatusId` are valid id's and exist in the appropriate tables.

```
SELECT PaymentStatusId, PostingStatusId 
FROM Posting
WHERE PostingId = @PostingId
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to update that field, paymentstatusID, only postingstatusid. Why do I need to include that field as well?

Comment: @Laziale - I understand that you are not trying to update that field.  I included the SELECT so you can test that the `PaymentStatusId` and `PostingStatusId` are valid (I.e. they exist in the other table) so the foreign key constraint can pass.

Comment: @Laziale - does the PaymentStatus table contain an entry with `ID` 2?

Comment: @Laziale - So when setting up the foreign key to `PaymentStatus` did you set it up on the wrong column?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running the following command:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Posting
WHERE  PaymentStatusId
NOT IN (
    SELECT PaymentStatusId
    FROM dbo.PaymentStatus
)
```

You probably have bad data in Posting table that is being flagged here. How it got in there...I would guess that the constraint was either created or recreated after the data was populated, and the WITH CHECK option was disabled.